# update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header

Tags: bash

After following this guide here on my Raspberry Pi 3: http://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-your-Raspberry-Pi-into-a-Portable-Bluetooth-A/?ALLSTEPS (Step 6)

I came across an error which says `update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header` when running `sudo update-rc.d bluetooth-agent defaults`.

This is what my bluetooth agent file looks like. Are my headers being applied incorrectly?

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#/etc/init.d/bluetooth-agent
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: bluetooth-agent
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog bluetooth pulseaudio
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Makes Bluetooth discoverable and connectable to 0000
### END INIT INFO

USER=root
HOME=/root
export USER HOME
case "$1" in
start)
echo "setting bluetooth discoverable"
sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan
start-stop-daemon -S -x /usr/bin/bluetooth-agent -c pi -b -- 0000
echo "bluetooth-agent startet pw: 0000"
;;
stop)
echo "Stopping bluetooth-agent"
start-stop-daemon -K -x /usr/bin/bluetooth-agent
;;
*)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/bluetooth-agent {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

That instructable is for Raspbian Wheezy, your Raspberry Pi 3 is most likely running Raspbian Jessie (RPi3 does't run on Wheezy). The major difference between the two is Wheezy was using System V (which used update-rc.d), while Jessie is using systemd instead (which is not using update-rc.d).
Either remove systemd and replace it with System V, or see how to perform the same task using systemd.

Comment: Systemd is backward compatible with this kind of script and you will find there is a little stack of them still used on the latest version of Raspbian.  That said, I agree if you are going to start learning how to implement an init service you might as well start learning the new way rather than the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **simple solution**:

> # Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog bluetooth pulseaudio

has the wrong format - there are no "$"'s in front of bluetooth and pulseaudio. So the correct line would be

> # Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog $bluetooth $pulseaudio

As mentioned in the answers init.d scripts are deprecated nowadays - systemd will *at some point* drop the init.d compatibility.

The **best solution** would contain a systemd service unit file and unit activation that fully replaces the above init.d script. 
So anyone: please don't argue about deprecation, give that answer here if you know it.
Until then: the simple solution works for now, I just tested it.